# Ruby on Rails: What to call in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a `next` method in the model.

```
 def self.next(comment, key = :id)
     self.where("#{key} > ?", comment.send(key)).first
 end
```

In my view I can say for example: (does not work)

```
= link_to "next", @comment.next(@comment)
```

What's the correct way to call this method?

routes.rb:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments do
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `next` as a class method (vs an instance method), so you need:

```
= link_to "next", Comment.next(@comment)
```

If you want to be able to call `@comment.next`, define the instance method as:

```
def next(key = :id)
  Comment.where("#{key} > ?", self.send(key)).first
end
```

Comment: @LiroyLeshed As in the answer?

Comment: Okay, now I get `undefined comment_path`

Comment: @LiroyLeshed Do you have a comment route?

Comment: Since you've nested the `resources :comments` under `resources :articles`, the route requires both objects: `article_comment_path(@comment.article, @comment)`. Your other option is to unnest `resources :comments` for direct paths - it's just a matter of how you want to organize your resources/URLs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good style that the model knows this, you should put it in the controller. You should try a gem called [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), this gem lets you paginate over the elements, so in your comments controller you could have something like:

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.order(id: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(1)
end
```

Then in your view, by just adding this kaminari helper:

```
<%= paginate @comment %>
```

You get the pagination bar below and everything works fine (gem's magic).

If you don't like this you could try to add that next method in the controller or find both next and current elements and link to the next element.

In my opinion the model is just a class that knows how to save and get information from the database and maybe some calculations with it's information, so all that logic related to the view should be elsewhere.

Comment: The code I wrote should do the pagination just fine. If you want to use the method in the controller you should pass an argument to it like the current id of the comment, so in  your controller you have

def show
  @ comment = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id])
  @ next_comment = Comment.where('id > ?', params[:comment_id]).first
end